# Why not able to download image from Facebook Graph API in Swift?

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, nsdata

Try to load image here:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: cover.source)
let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
```

url is:

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/89497497_154660109338731_1168155027756285952_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=b386c4&_nc_ohc=fDaLgthJw0AAX_jlQC4&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&_nc_tp=7&oh=3779157648b90be76cec54a5dd263e57&oe=5E9685ED
```

from browser I can download, but Xcode says:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “89497497_154660109338731_1168155027756285952_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=b386c4&_nc_ohc=fDaLgthJw0AAX_jlQC4&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&_nc_tp=7&oh=3779157648b90be76cec54a5dd263e57&oe=5E9685ED” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/kukodajanos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ticket-BE-gozvcezhcvkvavgwignicxedvdyw/Build/Products/Debug/https:/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/89497497_154660109338731_1168155027756285952_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=b386c4&_nc_ohc=fDaLgthJw0AAX_jlQC4&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&_nc_tp=7&oh=3779157648b90be76cec54a5dd263e57&oe=5E9685ED, NSUnderlyingError=0x104d10f20 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` for an external file/url, this init is only for local files.

Use `URL(string:)` instead

```
if let url = URL(string: cover.source) {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    ...
}
```